# Retrieving Movies Via Rotten Tomatoes API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

I would like to know how to retrieve movies from the Rotten Tomatoes Api using JavaScript/JQuery. I have looked over the documentation and looked at the examples but i am still no wiser as API's are new to me. If someone could give me an example of the following that would be great:

http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?apikey=[your_api_key]&limit=1

(I am aware i need to input my api key for it to function)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Is it possible to then insert this data into a clickable ListView where each link once clicked will open a new page and display further information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example API on the  Website, I created this sample code for your purpose - Getting Top Box Office Earning Movie. `limit=1` will return only the first movie on the sorted list.

To see the entire XML that contains all the JSON key/value you could retrieve, use [this link](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/Box_Office_Movies)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var apikey = "YourApiKeyHERE";
        var baseUrl = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0";

        // construct the uri with apikey
        var moviesSearchUrl = baseUrl + '/lists/movies/box_office.json?apikey=' + apikey + '&limit=1';

        $(document).ready(function() {

            // send off the query
            $.ajax({
            url: moviesSearchUrl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: searchCallback
            });
        });

        // callback for when we get back the results
        function searchCallback(data) {
            $(document.body).append('Found ' + data.total + ' results for Top Box Office Earning Movie');
            var movies = data.movies;
            $.each(movies, function(index, movie) {
            $(document.body).append('<h1>' + movie.title + '</h1>');
            $(document.body).append('<img src="' + movie.posters.thumbnail + '" />');
            });
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Is it possible to then insert this data into a clickable ListView where each link once clicked will open a new page and display further information?